# Array.shift() and modify value in a single line?

Tags: javascript, arrays, refactoring

This Javascript code removes the first file name from a file list and then removes its extension:

```
var fileNoExt = filelist.shift();
fileNoExt = fileNoExt.substr(0, fileNoExt.lastIndexOf('.'));
```

I'm curious - is it possible to turn this code into a one-liner?

Comment: You could even go as crazy as `var fileNoExt = (function(a) { return a.substr(0, a.lastIndexOf('.'));}(filelist.shift()));` Is it readable? No. Is it possible? Yes.

Comment: I guess the behaviour to remove the last character in case of no found dot is unwanted? Every of the answers below handles that case different, so choose the right one :-)

Comment: @FelixKling Indeed that's a radical approach ;)

Comment: @Bergi It is not a requirements since the script is reading a list of files which will always have extensions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using a regex?

If you want to enforce an extension after the `.`, use

```
var fileNoExt = filelist.shift().replace(/\.[^.]+$/, '');
```

otherwise, use

```
var fileNoExt = filelist.shift().replace(/\.[^.]*$/, '');
```

The second one matches `my_crazy_file.` and `my_crazy_file.extension` while the first only matches `my_crazy_file.extension`.

Comment: "I know, I'll use regexes" :)

Comment: @Sergio: Yet it's a valid usecase here and probably even faster than your array-split-join solution

Comment: @Bergi: probably. What I don't like about regexes is that they're pretty much write-only. You know what they're doing while you write them. Then you see one of them a week later and you have to *decipher* their content. Or maybe I'm just that bad with regexes.

Comment: @Sergio: Depends on how complex the expressions is ;) This one is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @Bergi I appreciate the edit, but if we really want to remove extensions, your suggestion would also include removing `.` at the end?  Example: `my_bad_filename.` vs `my_file_with_a_sane.extension`?  There is no extension in the first case.

Comment: @FelixKling: regex seems to be a better tool for the job in this case (than my split-join approach). At least it handles strings with no dots correctly.

Comment: @rtcherry: Yeah, now it would also remove trailing dots. That's the nice aspect of regexes, they're very flexible to express exactly what you want :-)

Comment: Very nice! I went with the first one since all files will have an extension anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a one-liner:

```
var filelist = ['file.name.ext', 'some.another.string']

filelist.shift().split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.') // 'file.name'
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"is it possible to turn this code into a one-liner?"*

Yes,

```
var fileNoExt = filelist[0].substr(0, filelist.shift().lastIndexOf('.'));
```

but why? It's clearer on two lines.

Comment: I am loving this. It's so "in your face". Brutal. You rock.